2018 Traverse Intermittent No-Start
Saturday morning, my wife went to the grocery store.  When she left, her 2018 Traverse started fine.  When she stopped at the traffic light to leave the parking lot, the ASS turned the car off like normal.  However, when the light turned green, it would not restart.  She then noticed that there was no power at all- no dash lights, stereo, nothing.  Not even the hazard lights would come on.  By the time I got there, a young man had used a jump box to jump the car and it started fine.  He then ran and got his multimeter and tested the alternator and voltage on the battery - no issues there.
Over the following four days, my wife drove the car as normal while I poked around on the internet trying to find an explanation.  She had no issues whatsoever until she went to leave work on Wednesday, at which point she called me and said it would not start again.  She was actually headed out of town, so she got an Uber to the airport while  I grabbed a coworker and a multimeter and went and poked around again.  We still could not find any issues.
My wife got home from her trip late last night, so we went to the office this morning with a jump box to see if we could get it started that way again.  To our surprise, when we got there, she got in and it started right up like nothing had happened.  She did notice that the clock was about 8 hours behind at that point.  I had her run it to AutoZone where they could do an actual load test on the battery (which is only about a year old, btw).  They reported that the battery was in perfect condition.
This feels completely random to me, especially since the battery is not draining.  The only thing that happened to the vehicle while it was sitting at the office was that we opened the door a few times while messing around with it so I thought maybe a door sensor had something to do with it, but that does not explain the first time it happened at a red light.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Usually when I see this type of thing, it is because of the connection between the battery and cabling. You might want to pull the posts on the battery and clean both the inside of the clamp as well as the post on the battery. Also ensure they are tight when putting them back in place.

Thank you for the suggestion @Paulster2 .  Question- does that mean the vehicle could actually lose all electrical power while going down the road?

Possibly, but not probable. Most likely the alternator would keep it running. While it shouldn't affect safety, it's not good for electrical components in the vehicle. The battery acts as a buffer to the electrical system. Most likely running down the road, if it becomes disconnected, it would most likely re-connect in short order due to vibration from the road.
